# Randomly choose an element of a hashset using java

Tags: java, hashset

I have a function where I have to `randomly` choose an element from a `HashSet` and then test if this element meets a condition. If the condition is true then return the chosen element otherwise we must randomly choose another element.

I tried the followin code :

```java
private  Number[] findClosest( int remCapacity, HashSet<Integer> remainingNodes, VrpProblem problem) {
    int[] demands = problem.getDemands();
    int bestNodeId = -1;
    Iterator<Integer> iter =  remainingNodes.iterator();
            
    Random random = new Random();
               
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        int nodeId = random.nextInt(remainingNodes.size());
                  
        if (demands[nodeId] > remCapacity) {
            continue;
        }    
        bestNodeId = nodeId;              
     }     
     return new Number[] {new Integer(bestNodeId)}  ;  
}
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to provide a method that returns a `randomIterator` to iterate over the set contents.  This works like a regular iterator except the elements are returned in a random order with no repeats.  It works as follows:

- The method first puts the set in a list. This is necessary so that individual elements may be retrieved.
- using an algorithm similar to `Fischer-Yates` start shuffling the list. The shuffle algorithm proceeds, one element at a time, as `next()` is called.
  The iterator works in `O(n)` time where `n` is the number of elements in the set.

```
Set<Integer> remainingNodes = 
Iterator<Integer> iter = randomIterator(remainingNodes);
    
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    int item = iter.next();
    // do the test
}
```

Method to return the iterator.

```
public static <T> Iterator<T>
        randomIterator(Collection<T> collection) {
    
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        List<T> copy = new ArrayList<>(collection);
        int nItems = copy.size();
        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nItems != 0;
        }
        
        public T next() {
            int k = (int) (Math.random() * nItems);
            T returnVal = copy.get(k);
            copy.set(k, copy.get(--nItems));
            return returnVal;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently not reading any value from the `remainingNodes` set. Depending on how expensive your solution can be, you can use the following approach:

1. Load all the `Set<Integer>` values in a `List<Integer>` instance.
2. Shuffle the list.
3. Iterate over the list and do your check.

So the source code can look like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(remainingNodes);
Collections.shuffle(list);
for (Integer value : list) {
    if (yourCheckTestHereWith_value_andOtherVariables) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that there might be a case where no value in the `Set` fits your condition. You have to define a fallback case after the `for` loop to handle that situation (throw exception, return `null`, etc.).